# Loading JavaScript in order of dependencies with Require.js

Tags: javascript, google-maps, requirejs

I'm diving into Require.js to build a Google Maps application using [this link](http://blog.millermedeiros.com/requirejs-2-0-delayed-module-evaluation-and-google-maps/) and [this link](http://experiencecraftsmanship.wordpress.com/2012/01/22/google-maps-hello-world-with-requirejs-and-jquery/) as a guide. **My goal is to build a modular application that loads "base" functionality first, and then I can "plug-in" client-specific functionality** - *without duplicating code*. So every project will use the "base" JS, but the client-specific JS will be different each project. Below is a list of my loading dependencies. This is the order I need things to load, with the previous item in the list needing to be fully loaded before moving onto the next:

1. Load jQuery and Google Maps API (I got this one working)
2. Load JavaScript to initialize my map on the page with base application functionality
3. Load additional/client-specific JavaScript.

I can get 1 and 2 to work just fine using this:

**main.js:**

```
require.config({
    paths:{
        jquery: "jquery-1.7.1.min",
        jqueryui: "jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min",
        async: "async",
        requiremap: "requiremap"
    }
});

require(
    [ "jquery", "jqueryui", "requiremap" ],
    function( $, jqueryui, requiremap ) {

    }
);
```

**requiremap.js:**

```
define(
    [ "async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" ],
    function() {
        require(['js/basemapfunctionality.js'], function() {

        });
    }
);
```

But now **I need to wait until #2 is completely loaded before loading #3**. Is this possible with Require.js, and if so, how? (and if not, are there alternative frameworks that can do this) I tried adding another nested require method to load the additional functionality (illustrated below), but it acts like #2 hasn't loaded yet.

```
define(
    [ "async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" ],
    function() {
        require(['js/basemapfunctionality.js'], function() {
            require(['js/additionalfunctionality.js'], function() {
                // now everything should be loaded, but it ain't
            });
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got this to work. Just had to break up the loading of Google Maps API, base functionality, and additional functionality into different modules and declare each in main.js.

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    paths:{
        jquery: "jquery-1.7.1.min",
        jqueryui: "jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min",
        async: "async",
        requiremap: "requiremap",
        basemapfunctionality: "basemapfunctionality",
        additionalfunctionality: "additionalfunctionality"
    }
});

require(
    [ "jquery", "jqueryui", "requiremap", "basemapfunctionality", "additionalfunctionality" ],
    function( $, jqueryui, requiremap, basemapfunctionality, additionalfunctionality ) {

    }
);
```

**requiremap.js**

```
define([ "async!https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" ], function() {});
```

**basemapfunctionality.js**

```
define(['requiremap'], function(requiremap) {
    // basemap functionality here
}
```

**additionalfunctionality.js**

```
define(['requiremap', 'basemapfunctionality'], function(requiremap, basemapfunctionality) {
    // additional functionality here
}
```

Comment: You should mark your own answer as accepted (give it the tick)! Good to hear you figured it out.

Comment: It also wouldn't hurt to share a code example of your solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much into RequireJS, but [this issue](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/114) and the commentary implies a way to resolve your question.

Relevant quote from the link:

> This is due to the interaction of `$.extend` and the order of execution of modules.
>
> In a built file, the 'other/config' module is evaluated before the inner call to
>   `require(['other/controller']`, an since `$.extend` only mixes in properties, it causes the problem. 
>   You can avoid it by using the `Object.create()` type of approach, where you create a new object whose
>   prototype is the `BaseConfig`, so that later, any properties you add to the `BaseConfig` will show up
>   automatically on that new object.

Answer (score 0):

See [**Asynchronously Loading the API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API). There is a callback parameter where you can indicate a callback function that will be called when the API is fully loaded.

Comment: As I stated in my question, I can get the Maps API to load and my "base" functionality to load after the Maps API without any problems. The problem is that I need to wait until base functionality JS is fully loaded before loading another JS module.

Comment: If you're using a callback, inside the callback function you can do first loadBase() and then loadClientStuff()

Comment: I don't know whst Require.js does,whether it load sequentially or asynchronously.